# Pop up form in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I am building my portfolio web-site and for it I need to use a reagistration form . On many web sites I have seen pop up registration forms . For example when you click on register button a form pops up (at the same time you remain in the same page ) and you can fill in the forms and submit . So I mean does javascript or jquery have that type of code that i can integrate to my sites code to get that type of pop form .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is done with JavaScript and can be done with jQuery. Here's a bare bones example to get you started: it'll toggle the display for the registration form, but you might want to add some animations in the jQuery or styles/positioning in the CSS.

HTML:

```
<button>Register</button>

<div id="popup">
    <form action="post" action="/register">
        <!-- form stuff... -->
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#popup').toggle();
});
```

Comment: For a literal 'popup', you might be looking for .dialog() instead of .toggle() which will show/hide the `div(popup)` wherever you have it in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Juice UI](http://juiceui.com/).  It wraps jQueryUI stuff up into asp.net server controls.  The [dialog](http://juiceui.com/controls/dialog) control is likely what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery UI simply because of it's documentation, support, and features.

**[Here's a working jsFiddle example of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kGKhj/)**

Here's the HTML Structure ->

```
<div><a href="#" id="register"> Register </a></div>
<div class="register-popup">
  <form>
    <label for="fname"> First Name </label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/><br/>
    <label for="fname"> First Name </label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="lname"><br/><br/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery ->

```
$(function(){
  $('#register').on('click', function(){
     $('.register-popup').dialog('open');  
  });
  $('.register-popup').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: '280',
    height: '300',
    title: 'Register Here',
    buttons: {
      'Register Now!': function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'path/to/registration/controller',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).find('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
              console.log('This is where the data is returned from your controller to the web page');
              $(this).dialog('close');                  
            }
        });                 
      }
    }       
  });    
});
```

**[Here's the link to the jQuery UI Dialog Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)**

Comment: Can't get much more of an answer than this.